# Unable to create annotation with multiple bound generic class arguments

Tags: java, generics, annotations, bounded-wildcard

I'm trying to create an annotation which can accept multiple classes as input. Typical usage would be

```
@Prerequisites{FirstPrerequisite.class, SecondPrerequisite.class}
```

For this I can create an annotation as shown below

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface Prerequisites {
    public Class<?>[] value();
}
```

I want to restrict the types that are allowed in the prerequisites annotation. If I give something like `public Class<? extends Dependency>[] value();` It is working however, the problem is My FirstPrerequisite and SecondsPrerequisite may bot be extended from same type. I tried the following but none seemed to work, they are giving compilation errors.

```
public Class<? extends Dependency & TestCaseStep>[] value();
public Class<? extends Dependency , TestCaseStep>[] value();
public Class<T extends Dependency & TestCaseStep>[] value();
```

How to bound Generics to take inputs of two different types?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a marker interface and have your classes implement the interface. You can then provide a bound with that interface type.

Another alternative is to simply move the constraint checking at runtime instead of at compile time. Have your annotation processor validate the `Class` arguments that were provided.

Comment: May be second options is for me because I have to work with two different types created in past now, I'm supposed to bring them together. Thanks.